# when you click a record on a subform the record in the mainform must show

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

when i click a record in the subform it must display that specific record in the mainform my Mainform is Products and Subform is Products Subform2

My code does not do the trick any help examples will help. Thanks

Code

```
Forms!Products!Products_Subform2.Form!ProdID
```

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem with one line of code.

Comment: im new to access

Comment: Not relevant, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

On the main form, use a control (textbox) with this *ControlSource*:

```
=[Forms]![Products]![NameOfYourSubformControl].[Form]![ProdID]
```

No VBA code is needed.